# Ignite Compute application incorrect result for the sample app - check example

Tags: c#, ignite, calculation

I am just playing with Ignite in C#. I am doing the basic distributed computation as per sample in the website, however I get a wrong result.

I expect to get 10 for this "Count of chars" however Computer.Call returns 36. Even passing "Count" which is expected to be 5 is returning 12. This is based on the sample in website https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/getting-started-2

Is it something related to C#/Java conversion or what is going on?

```
static void Compute()
{
    using (var ignite = Ignition.Start())
    {
        var funcs = "Count of chars".Split(' ')
          .Select(word => new ComputeFunc { Word = word });

        ICollection<int> res = ignite.GetCompute().Call(funcs);

        var sum = res.Sum();

        Console.WriteLine(">>> Total number of characters in the phrase is '{0}'.", sum);
    }
}

class ComputeFunc : IComputeFunc<int>
{
    public string Word { get; set; }

    public int Invoke()
    {
        return Word.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your code, the expected result is 12 (count - 5, of - 2, chars - 2). I executed the code (using Apache Ignite 2.5) and received the correct result - 12. Which Ignite and DotNet Framework versions do you use?

Comment: Hi Roman, Thanks for the reply. I actually found the issue myself. The problem was that I was using var remoteCluster = ignite.GetCluster().ForRemotes(); and the class deployed in the Remote node had slightly different code and that is why I was getting unexpected result.